# Serve react component as a REST APIs

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I have a ready to serve react app. I want to serve my app as a REST endpoint.

If anyone wants to use my component, he can import the bundle script and use the component.

How can I do that?

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to publish that component on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) instead. That way your consumers can add it as a dependency, version control, etc.

Comment: I have already created and published `npm` package.
But I want my component to be used by non-react application.
So for that may be I need to create a namespace, But I don't know how to create it from react component.